# How to set the remote host to a domain name with dynamic IP in *swan client?

Tags: vpn, ipsec, dynamic-dns, openswan

I am now setting a vpn client for my university's own L2TP/IPSec VPN network, using both openswan, libreswan and strongswan (for different distros).

Here is the problem:

The remote site (VPN server) is a domain name (say xxx.com) with multiple IP addresses (say 123.123.123.100-123.123.123.103).

In this case, how should I set the conn part?

I have tried something like:

```
conn university
    ...
    left=%defaultroute
    right=xxx.com
    ...
    auto=route
```

Which seems not working, since when *swan start, it parses xxx.com and setup the route by the IP returned by the DNS request (say 123.123.123.100). Then when I make a connection to xxx.com, it may parse the domain again and get a different IP (say 123.123.123.101), and the connection will not go through *swan.

I have also tried the `rightsubnet` option, but I don't know what should be the `right` option. If I just use `%any`, *swan will give some error like `No route to destination` (something like that, cannot remember) and refuse to add the conn.

Now my workaround is:

```
conn university0
    right=123.123.123.100
    also=university
    auto=route

conn university1
    right=123.123.123.101
    also=university
    auto=route

conn university2
    right=123.123.123.102
    also=university
    auto=route

conn university3
    right=123.123.123.103
    also=university
    auto=route

conn university4
    right=123.123.123.104
    also=university
    auto=route

conn university
    left=%defaultroute
    ...
```

...which works, but seems ugly and non-scalable.

In the past, when I use racoon, I can use the `setkey` command to modify the SPD directly, so I can set policies for the corresponding IPs directly.

I think this case is common and there will be a solution designed for this case in *swan. Anyone can help?